# Overriding main CSS

Tags: html, css, opacity

I'm trying to get the "div.transbox table" to not have the opacity from "div.transbox".

If I try removing the table from the main transbox CSS then I can't get the table to sit on top of "div.transbox".

Any help much appreciated

```
div.transbox
  {
  width:1000px;
  height:1500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid black;
  opacity:0.8;
  z-index:-1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  }

div.transbox p
  {
  margin:30px 40px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#000000;
  z-index:-1;
  }

div.transbox table
  {
  margin:30px 40px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:black;
  background-color:#cccccc;
  z-index:99;
  }
```

Comment: Create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can try some solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make child elements "more visible" when the parent element has an adjusted `opacity`.

`opacity`'s value ranges from 0 to 1, and the properties stack. In the example below, the "real" opacity of the `<p>` element is not 0.5, but 0.8 * 0.5 = 0.4:

```
.transbox   { opacity: 0.8; }
.transbox p { opacity: 0.5; }
```

Comment: Okay thanks for clearing that up. If I separate it off from the transbox css how can I get it to sit in its position that it was originally in?

Comment: @Samuelofc Add `position:relative;` to `.transbox`, and position the `p` element absolutely with `position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width: ... ; height: ...`, where `...` are the width and height of your element. There are better solutions though. Modern browser support semi-transparent colors through [rgba or hsla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/color_value#RGBa_%28red-green-blue-alpha%29_rgba%28R.2CG.2CB.2Ca%29), for example.